# How to increment next K elements around an index

Tags: java, arrays

Suppose we have an array of size N. We are going through this array using for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      arr[i]++;
}
```

How to increment next **K** *(K < N)* elements on both sides of index ***i*** as well as index ***i*** itself for every ***i*** *(means range from arr[i - K] to arr[i + K])*? We need to check if we're still in array boundaries too. If the distance between the last (first) element and ***i*** is less than **K** then increment as much elements as fits.

Comment: what do you mean exactly with "on both sides of index _i_ ? Are you searching for a solution that doesn't need the for loop?

Comment: @cyberbrain both sides means a range from arr[i - K] to arr[i + K]. we need to increment this range of elements on each iteration of a for loop

Comment: You can just loop through the range `Math.max(0,i-k)` and `Math.min(N-1,i+k)`.